# How to express that my lovely personality got some of my employers to recommend me for other projects/contracts?

Tags: sentence-construction, idiomatic-language

Maybe I am treading on proofreading territory, but I've been struggling with this particular problem for a while now.

My supervisor says that I should mention in my resume (under the related job) that my contract was renewed and extended multiple times [because they really loved to have me on their teams]. He wants me to highlight that in addition to my hard skills, I am also accountable, thorough, and very pleasant to work with.

I am struggling to express the following succinctly in my resume/CV.

- Professor A hired me as a Research Assistant. I performed really, really well. Professor A was impressed with my work, and so he advised Professor B to hire me on his project.​
- Professor B was impressed hearing about my work, and so he offered me a contract.
- Professors A and B were once again happy with my work, so they spoke of me to professors C and D.​
- Professors C and D also hired me for two of their projects.​ They extended my contract.
- In the meantime, Professor B renewed my contract several times and hired me for different projects.​

I have tried the following (should be my opening statement under the specific job title):

> Recognition of my enthusiasm, accountability, and excellent attention to detail led to multiple contract renewals and extensions [under which I worked on various projects for different professors].

**Specific problems:** First, it completely fails to indicate that some of these professors recommended me to their colleagues, without me having to apply for that particular job/contract. It was some of these professors who sought me out. I want this sentence to somehow indicate that I got the contracts on recommendation. Second, it just doesn't sound good overall.

What can I change in this sentence to ensure that it does what I want it to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this would fit:

> Recognition of my enthusiasm, accountability, and excellent attention to detail elicited enthusiastic recommendations by my [professors|supervisors], which led to multiple contract renewals and extensions.

Comment: Why did you use "by" instead of "from" in "recommendations by"?

Comment: I think it's because you can say *I was recommended by...*, but not *I was recommended from...*   You can say *I received recommendations from...*, and maybe with *elicited*, *from* would work better. Maybe *elicited supervisor recommendations*, avoiding the preposition choice.